# git pull added tons of untracked files and modified files

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I am not very familiar with git as I just use it in the most basic manner. Lately I've been running into this strange behavior which makes no sense to me and causes a huge disturbance in my productivity. For certain branches when I run `git pull` instead of just getting the latest commits from the remote repository like I expect, I get an ENORMOUS list of modified/deleted/added files as well as an enormous list of untracked files. The branch I am pulling from is our team's master branch. I am just trying to keep my local copy of master in sync. What are these other untracked files showing up as well as these modified files? I didn't touch any of these other files.

What makes the problem worse is that I can't delete these untracked files or anything. I've tried `git clean -fx' and it only removes 3-4 files but still leaves hundreds. At this point I just want to get rid of all of these files, delete the branch, and pull the branch from remote again.

I tried doing the following:

```sh
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/<remote_branch_name>
```

but I received an error because Git couldn't create a symbolic link. I am using Git on Windows.

Why is `git pull` doing this, and what should I do?

EDIT: I was finally able to run the `git reset` command when I ran my prompt as an admin, but it still doesn't explain this weird `git pull` behavior.

Comment: If files are modified/deleted/added when executing a `git pull`, then someone else pushed the changes to the remote repository. So, you are pulling those changes to your local repo.

Comment: yes, but thats the point of pull right? I want to get latest changes from remote branch.

Comment: Correct. So, why do you think you're getting untracked files if they were pulled from the remote repository?

Comment: It's tempting to point to the *as an admin* part as the source of the problem. It may well *be* the source of the problem; there's not enough here to say for sure. It is however worth noting that `git pull` just means *run `git fetch` to get new commits, then run a second Git command to incorporate the new commits*. It's *probably* the second command that's going wrong. If you want to figure it out once and for all and fix it, it's best to run each command separately, so that you can drill into the appropriate details.

Comment: is the second command a merge?

Comment: `git pull` is essentially `git fetch && git merge`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the 'git pull' action did not complete successfully.

It is possible that you modified some of the files as an admin, and when pulling as non-admin user git tries to modify or delete a file and has no permissions to it.

Therefore you stay in some half baked state.

What do you see when you run `git status`?
Is there any error in the `git pull`?

Comment: there was no error in the git pull. the permission issues only affected the symlinked files, which were 3. However, when I ran the pull, there were hundreds of other modified files.